# When executing a stored procedure, the loop inside the procedure is running infinitely

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
USE CIS111_BookStoreMC
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('spAssetInfo') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROC spAssetInfo 
GO

CREATE PROC spAssetInfo

AS

SELECT AssetID, Description, Cost, PurchaseDate 
INTO #temptable
FROM Assets

ALTER TABLE #temptable ADD CompleteDepreciationYear DATE

DECLARE @value MONEY;
SET @value = 0.00;
DECLARE @j INT;
DECLARE @depreciationNum INT;
SET @j = 1;
WHILE (@j <= 14)
    BEGIN
        SET @depreciationNum = 0;
        SET @value = (select Cost From Assets Where AssetID = @j);
        SET @j = @j + 1;
        WHILE(@value > 0)
            BEGIN  
                SET @value = @value - (@value * 0.2);
                SET @depreciationNum = @depreciationNum + 1;
            END
        INSERT INTO #temptable
            (CompleteDepreciationYear)
        VALUES
            (DATEADD(year, @depreciationNum, CAST((select PurchaseDate From Assets Where AssetID = @j-1) AS DATE)))
    END

SELECT * FROM #temptable
```

I have been trying to figure this out for hours, basically I am trying to show an Asset Inventory with PurchaseDate and the date the item is completely depreciated, the asset depreciates 20% per year. I tried to do a temporary table and copy some of the assets table columns to it then adding a column for the date when the asset completely depreciates.

For some reason, when I try executing the procedure as such 'EXEC spAssetInfo', the query runs forever

I forgot to include it in the screenshot but I also have
SELECT * FROM #temptable
to show the table when the procedure is executed

Comment: HI Mohammad, welcome to the SO. Please update the question with your code as text. Thanks

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Even if you managed to fixed the infinite loop problem, it is still a loop. Rewrite your query using set-based.

Comment: Side note, if you are using a `WHILE` in SQL, you are probably doing it wrong. SQL is a set based language so it excels at set based solutions. Unsurprisingly it is therefore awful at iterative processes that programming languages excel at. I could probably count the number of proper reasons to use a `WHILE`/`CURSOR` in SQL Server on my fingers

Comment: I edited it and removed the image

Comment: How would you recommend I get the date the asset is completely depreciated otherwise? @squirrel

Comment: I would suggest asking a *new* qusetion, @MohamadChaker , showing the solution you currently have, providing sample data and expected results, and explaining the problem you are solving. Then ask, in that question, how you can change it from a iterative solution to a set based one. **Do not** edit this question to ask that; such edits will be rollback and could result in downvotes as you would be significantly changing the question you are asking (which is severely frowned upon; especially after you've received answers).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this part:
[image]

Make a track and you will see that  those two conditions are indefinitely (first is never false and the second is never true).

```
Money=5
Money=5*0,2 = 1
Money=1*0,2 = 0,2
Money=0,2*0,2 = 0,04 and then you have a loop ;)
```

Comment: oh I see, even tho I am subtracting it is basically never going to go below 0, what do you recommend I do to get the date when the item is completely depreciated? @XraySensei

Comment: Completely depreciated is relative term. You need to define what value it should be and that can not be 0. I would put 0.1

Comment: @MohamadChaker - Is this depreciation rule your own?  If so, just decide on some level of rounding, such as ***rounding Up*** to the next whole number (be that a dollar or a rupee or whatever).  Then an item currently valued at 1 will depreciate by "(1 * 0.2) rounded up, which is 1", so depreciating to exactly 0, and exiting the loop.  If the depreciation rule is from a real business, ask the accounting team Exactly what they Actually do, because it's not what you've coded.  Then come back to StackOverflow with another question, showing the working loop, and ask how to do it without a loop.

Comment: well this is for a school project where I have to implement a database architecture for a bookstore, I am asked to created a stored procedure that Shows an asset inventory along with the current value (minus 20% depreciation per year). Also show the year when each item will be completely depreciated @MatBailie

Comment: @MohamadChaker - Then accept this answer, as it is correct, and ***just decide on some level of rounding*** to avoid items being depreciated until they're worth 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000001.  Then, once you have the loop working with some rounding, ask another question on Stack Overlfow on how to implement the same logic without a loop.